# pm2 kills my nuxt process after a random time

Tags: centos, nuxt.js, pm2

i've built a nuxt app then i used 'nuxt build' to build then i uploaded it to a VPS (trendy for web solutions)

i have done what everyone on the internet did and i ran pm2 to serve this app so i ran 'pm2 start'

the problem is after like 10minutes+ the process dies without any error and without any trace of any problem

this is  my ecosystem.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'Photostation',
      script: './node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js',
      args: 'start',
      instances: 1,
      kill_timeout : 108000,
      autorestart: true
    }
  ]
}
```

this is pm2 logs (it doesn't show anything useful )

```
2021-10-27T15:46:43: PM2 log: App [Photostation:0] starting in -cluster mode-
2021-10-27T15:46:43: PM2 log: App [Photostation:0] online
2021-10-27T15:48:01: PM2 log: Stopping app:Photostation id:0
2021-10-27T15:48:01: PM2 log: App name:Photostation id:0 disconnected
2021-10-27T15:48:01: PM2 log: App [Photostation:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
2021-10-27T15:48:01: PM2 log: pid=2482 msg=process killed
2021-10-27T15:48:58: PM2 log: App [Photostation:0] starting in -cluster mode-
2021-10-27T15:48:58: PM2 log: App [Photostation:0] online
2021-10-27T15:50:45: PM2 log: Stopping app:Photostation id:0
2021-10-27T15:50:45: PM2 log: App name:Photostation id:0 disconnected
2021-10-27T15:50:45: PM2 log: App [Photostation:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
2021-10-27T15:50:45: PM2 log: pid=2590 msg=process killed
2021-10-27T15:50:49: PM2 log: App [Photostation:0] starting in -cluster mode-
2021-10-27T15:50:49: PM2 log: App [Photostation:0] online
2021-10-27T16:17:06: PM2 log: ===============================================================================
2021-10-27T16:17:06: PM2 log: --- New PM2 Daemon started ----------------------------------------------------
2021-10-27T16:17:06: PM2 log: Time                 : Wed Oct 27 2021 16:17:06 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
2021-10-27T16:17:06: PM2 log: PM2 version          : 5.1.2
2021-10-27T16:17:06: PM2 log: Node.js version      : 14.15.4
2021-10-27T16:17:06: PM2 log: Current arch         : x64
2021-10-27T16:17:06: PM2 log: PM2 home             : /home/.pm2
2021-10-27T16:17:06: PM2 log: PM2 PID file         : /home/.pm2/pm2.pid
2021-10-27T16:17:06: PM2 log: RPC socket file      : /home/.pm2/rpc.sock
2021-10-27T16:17:06: PM2 log: BUS socket file      : /home/.pm2/pub.sock
2021-10-27T16:17:06: PM2 log: Application log path : /home/.pm2/logs
2021-10-27T16:17:06: PM2 log: Worker Interval      : 30000
2021-10-27T16:17:06: PM2 log: Process dump file    : /home/.pm2/dump.pm2
2021-10-27T16:17:06: PM2 log: Concurrent actions   : 2
2021-10-27T16:17:06: PM2 log: SIGTERM timeout      : 1600
2021-10-27T16:17:06: PM2 log: ===============================================================================
```

on my laptop (windows) it works 24/7 (same built files,same everything)

the VPS uses linux

i can't figure the solution, please help me out here

thanks in advance